# jsch ssh connection can't get authorized_keys

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

i'm trying to make a connection via ssh from windows to a unix server 
my goal to have it in my java app so i cann run command without inputting passwords on each connect

right now i'm trying to understand what i'm doing wrong with keys

I generated a key in Tectia and uploaded it to server; 
I can see it in .ssh as  `2798 Apr 17 10:56 authorized_keys`

my connection setup looks like this

```
...
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.setKnownHosts("~/.ssh/know_hosts");
jsch.addIdentity("~/.ssh/authorized_keys");

System.out.println("identity added ");
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
System.out.println("session created.");

session.connect();
System.out.println("Connected");
....
```

and as a result of this i'm getting this error

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\User\ .ssh\authorized_keys (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

it's looking for the key on my local computer and not connecting to the server

what am I going wrong with these keys ?

Comment: Does the public key file exist in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? Is `C:\Users\User.ssh\authorized_keys` really part of the error message or did you change your username? If so, did you accidentally remove a backslash?

Comment: @TheBlackIPs yea i accidentally removed that backslash, thx for pointing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `addIdentity` is a **local** path to your **private** key.

Instead, you are giving it a path to a file that:

1. Would contain a **public** key;
2. Does not exit **locally** anyway.

Comment: ok, I found where is my private key is stored on windows machine; now when I use my private key i get this - invalid privatekey: [B@5e025e70 ... ; do you know something about this ? seems like it doesn't like that my key start with  ---- BEGIN SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----

Comment: Well, that's a new question and you have actually asked it already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55734483/850848 -- I believe that I have answered this question. And we can continue in the other one. Though there you claim a different format than in this comment.